# How to determine week days like first sunday, second sunday, third sunday .... by passing a date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to determine either the given day is the first, second, third, fourth or fifth week days of the month. So, far I have tried code as follows:

```
Date.prototype.getWeekOfMonth = function(exact) {
            var month = this.getMonth()
                , year = this.getFullYear()
                , firstWeekday = new Date(year, month, 1).getDay()
                , lastDateOfMonth = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate()
                , offsetDate = this.getDate() + firstWeekday - 1
                , index = 1 // start index at 0 or 1, your choice
                , weeksInMonth = index + Math.ceil((lastDateOfMonth + firstWeekday - 7) / 7)
                , week = index + Math.floor(offsetDate / 7)
            ;
            if (exact || week < 2 + index) return week;
            return week === weeksInMonth ? index + 5 : week;
        };
```

```
var weekOfMonth = date.getWeekOfMonth();
```

This is returning week of the month instead of weekdays of the month.

For example: `2016-06-02` June 02, 2019 is returning as `weekOfMonth = 2` instead I want to get it as `1` because it is the first Sunday of the month. I want to have first, second weekdays of the month not first, second of the month.

Comment: This is a hairy problem, because a given year could have 52 or 53 weeks, depending on how you define a week-year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this.

```js
function nthWeekdayOfMonth(weekday, date) {
  var count = 1, i = 1;
  var idate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1); 
  var ddate = date.getDate();
  while (true) {
    if (idate.getDay() === weekday || i >= ddate) {
      count++;
      if (i >= ddate) {
        if (idate.getDay() != weekday && i >= ddate) {
          count--;
        }
        break;
      }
    }

    idate.setDate(idate.getDate() + 1);
    i++;
  }
  return count;
}

var date = new Date("2016-06-02");
console.log(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth());
console.log("Week of month starting with sunday is ",nthWeekdayOfMonth(0, date));
```